# How to remove PHP array

Tags: php, image, forms, post, upload

We are trying to merge a new image upload field **image_cover** to our existing PHP code. We currently have 3 HTML fields, the first 2 are **image0**, **image1** array, and we just added **image_cover**. We want to use this new field the same our **image0**, **image1** uploads without an array as it is only 1 image to be uploaded in that field. This is our  code:

```
$inames = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    if (!($_FILES[image . $x]['name'] == "")) {
        $y = $x + 1;
        if ($_FILES['image$x']['size'] > $site_config['image_max_filesize'])
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("INVAILD_FILE_SIZE_IMAGE"), 1);
        $uploaddir = $site_config["uploads_dir"] . "/images/";
        $ifile = $_FILES[image . $x]['tmp_name'];
        $im = getimagesize($ifile);
        if (!$im[2])
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), sprintf(T_("INVALID_IMAGE"), $y), 1);
        if (!array_key_exists($im['mime'], $allowed_types))
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("INVALID_FILETYPE_IMAGE"), 1);
        $ret = SQL_Query_exec("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'files'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($ret);
        $next_id = $row['Auto_increment'];
        $ifilename = $next_id . $x . $allowed_types[$im['mime']];
        $copy = copy($ifile, $uploaddir . $ifilename);
        if (!$copy)
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), sprintf(T_("IMAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED"), $y), 1);
        $inames[] = $ifilename;
    }
}
```

Our query is as follows (we added `$icover`)

```
$ret = SQL_Query_exec("INSERT INTO table (filename, owner, name, descr, image_cover, image1, image2, category, added, info, size, numfiles, save_as, rules, external, nfo, filelang, anon, last_action) VALUES (".sqlesc($fname).", '".$CURUSER['id']."', ".sqlesc($name).", ".sqlesc($descr).", '".$icover[0]."', '".$inames[0]."', '".$inames[1]."', '".$catid."', '" . get_date_time() . "', '".$info."', '".$size."', '".$filecount."', ".sqlesc($fname).", '".$rules."', '".$external."', '".$details."', '".$langid."','$anon', '".get_date_time()."')");
```

The HTML fields

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type='file' name='image_cover' size='50' />
<input type='file' name='image0' size='50' />
<input type='file' name='image1' size='50' />
```

Our column is set in place and is a matching renamed copy of the **image1**, **image0** columns in our table. How can we do this? Thank you so much, stumped!

Comment: pay attention to this part of code `if (!($_FILES[image . $x]['name'] == "")) { `and put ` $_FILE['image_cover ']['size'] > $site_config['image_max_filesize']`

Comment: I still cant come up with a solution to this, I've tried several combinations.

Comment: also `'image$x'` this won't work change '' to "" and you need to have also case with this `_cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you might want to decouple the image upload procedure from querying for the 'next ID' in your DB table. Rename the files with an identifier from their relational record, like a Post's title or a User's name, etc. For the sake of example below, Ill just use the current timestamp.

Secondly, your query wont work as it stands, as the `$icover` var isnt created.

To demonstrate this in the most brutally simple way possible, you could just extract the image processing code from the loop, and run it once more for the image cover:

```
$time = time();
$inames = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    if (!($_FILES[image . $x]['name'] == "")) {
        $y = $x + 1;
        if ($_FILES['image$x']['size'] > $site_config['image_max_filesize'])
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("INVAILD_FILE_SIZE_IMAGE"), 1);
        $uploaddir = $site_config["uploads_dir"] . "/images/";
        $ifile = $_FILES[image . $x]['tmp_name'];
        $im = getimagesize($ifile);
        if (!$im[2])
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), sprintf(T_("INVALID_IMAGE"), $y), 1);
        if (!array_key_exists($im['mime'], $allowed_types))
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("INVALID_FILETYPE_IMAGE"), 1);
        $ifilename = $time . '_' . $x . $allowed_types[$im['mime']];
        $copy = copy($ifile, $uploaddir . $ifilename);
        if (!$copy)
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), sprintf(T_("IMAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED"), $y), 1);
        $inames[] = $ifilename;
    }
}

    if (!($_FILES['image_cover']['name'] == "")) {
        if ($_FILES['image_cover']['size'] > $site_config['image_max_filesize'])
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("INVAILD_FILE_SIZE_IMAGE"), 1);
        $uploaddir = $site_config["uploads_dir"] . "/images/";
        $ifile = $_FILES['image_cover']['tmp_name'];
        $im = getimagesize($ifile);
        if (!$im[2])
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), sprintf(T_("INVALID_IMAGE"), $y), 1);
        if (!array_key_exists($im['mime'], $allowed_types))
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), T_("INVALID_FILETYPE_IMAGE"), 1);

        $ifilename = $time . '_image_cover' . $allowed_types[$im['mime']];
        $copy = copy($ifile, $uploaddir . $ifilename);
        if (!$copy)
            show_error_msg(T_("ERROR"), sprintf(T_("IMAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED"), 1), 1);
        $inames['image_cover'] = $ifilename;
    }
```

(and then use `$inames['image_cover']` in your query...)

For further refinement, extract the error handling above into its own callback, and then encapsulate the entire image processing procedure into a callback.

Instead of using the anticipated ID in the image filenames, you could also implement a relational table which holds the primary key of the record these images relate to. Then use that primary key in the image filenames (instead of the `$time` value I created for demonstration).